# equalsIgnoreCase в switch?

Tags: java

Вопрос в шапке, возможно-ли как-то применить equalsignorecase в switch?

Я имею вот такой код. Возможно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы case принимал любое значение. Например
hElp, HELP, hELP и т.д

```java
                switch (args[0]) {
                    case "info":
                    case "help":
                        if (player.hasPermission("nce.command.help")) {
                            showCommandInfo(player);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "cases":
                        if (player.hasPermission("nce.command.cases")) {
                            openCasesMenu(player);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "menu":
                        if (player.hasPermission("nce.command.menu")) {
                            openMainMenu(player);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "reload":
                        if (player.hasPermission("nce.command.reload")) {
                            reloadPlugin();
                        }
                        break;
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, нельзя. `switch()` сравнивает переданное значение с тем, что указаны в `case:`. Но можно поступить по другому - переведите строку в нижний регистр с помощью метода `.toLowerCase()` и потом уже её сравнивайте:

```
switch ( args[0].toLowerCase() ) {
    case "info":
    case "help":
    ....
```